# Initialise directive when API is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which data is dependent on the API response. Because `$compile` of directive is run before the API is done, the directive state is wrong.

How could I fix this? Is there a configuration for directive, controller or anything in AngularJs that will tell the element to wait until the API is done?

Comment: Impossible to tell without an example.  What type of state inside the directive is dependent?

Comment: If possible, can you post some part of the code?

Comment: is it possible to not load html of entered route, until the API is done?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is, you can use ng-if directive to create the dom when your API is done.

```
<your-directive ng-if="isAPIExecuted"></your-directive>
```

And in your API success handler,

```
Test.get().then(function(){
   $scope.isAPIExecuted = true;
});
```

Edit:

If you are using ui-router, then to load your html once the API is executed, you can us resolve as follows:

```
.state{
  controller: '',
  templateUrl: '',
  resolve: {
            data: function($q, $timeout){
                // Replace this code with your API call

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function(){
                    return deferred.resolve();
                },10000);

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
}
```

So it will load html and controller only once your promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the API calls in the router, eg:

```
$routeProvider
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: function(messageService){
            return messageService.getMessage();
    }
}
```

})

Then you can inject the resolve attributes in the controller:

```
app.controller("newsController", function (message) {
    $scope.message = message;
});
```

Got the above code from http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx so check that out for more details.

If you want something more specific, please provide some code.